# Exception while building the Workitem store

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to query some workitems from TFS, but while GetService, I am getting exception. Can someone help me.

```
 ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XX", "XXX");
 Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, networkCredential);
 tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
 WorkItemStore Store = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
```

**Error**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear: You're missing `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy`. Install the TFS 2012 object model and add a reference to that assembly to your project. I say 2012 because version `11.x` indicates TFS 2012. 12 would be 2013, and 14 would be 2015.

Comment: You might be better using the TFS Object Model available on Nuget as it does not require TE to be installed.